# how to do an inequation using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

So i want to do something like that using `xsl` if the ranking is **between 1 and 3** then set the **background color to green** else if the ranking is **between 20 and 23** then set it to **red**
here is my `xsl` code

```
            <xsl:attribute name="style">
                    <xsl:if test=" 1 &lt;= ranking &lt;= 3" >
                        <!-- 1<= ranking >=3 -->
                        background-color: LightGreen;
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test=" 20 &lt;= ranking &gt;= 23" >
                        <!-- 20<= ranking >=23 -->
                        background-color: red;
                    </xsl:if>
            </xsl:attribute>
```

my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="statistiques.xsl" ?> 

<statistical_team>
    <team>
        <team>Real Madrid</team>
        <ranking>1</ranking>
    </team>
    <team>
        <team>Barcelone</team>
        <ranking>8</ranking>
    </team>
    <team>
        <team>Juventus</team>
        <ranking>2</ranking>
    </team>
    <team>
        <team>PSG</team>
        <ranking>5</ranking>
    </team>
    <team>
        <team>Bayern</team>
        <ranking>4</ranking>
    </team>
</statistical_team>
```

but it doesn't work
and also is there a method to make this **process dynamic** because if we add a **24th team the code will never work**

Comment: You should post your input XML if you want someone to help your with your code.

Comment: ok i will do it

Comment: I don't know how your input data is provided but most likely your first condition could be ranking &lt; 4 and your second condition could be ranking &gt; 19.

Comment: @Sebastien but if we modified the xml file we will have to do the same to the to the xsl file I want to automate this task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `1 <= rank <= 3` is actually allowed in XPath 1.0, but it doesn't mean what you think - it's sufficiently confusing that it was disallowed in XPath 2.0. You want `1 <= rank and rank <= 3`.

The XPath 1.0 meaning is that `1<=rank` is evaluated as a boolean, which is then treated as a number (0 or 1) and the resulting number is compared with 3. Since both 0 and 1 are <= 3, the result is always true.

Comment: so what is the solution in your opinion

Comment: @ChiTangLi:  This answer clearly provides the solution to the first problem of why your range tests failed to work as you expected.   Regarding the second problem of how to make the code dynamic, simply add as many subranges as are required, then add a catchall such as `ranking > 23` for the remaining cases.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do it simply like this :

```
<xsl:attribute name="style">
                    <xsl:if test="ranking &lt;= 3" >
                        <!-- 1<= ranking >=3 -->
                        background-color: LightGreen;
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="ranking &gt;= 20" >
                        <!-- 20<= ranking >=23 -->
                        background-color: red;
                    </xsl:if>
            </xsl:attribute>
```